# Сокращение кода с if в C

Tags: c, if

Есть код с кучей if else, как можно его сократить, если можно с объяснением. Буду очень благодарен!

```
#include<stdio.h>  
float taxIsrael(float salary, float taxAllowance);
float netSalary(float salary, float taxAllowance);
int main(){
    float tax = taxIsrael (50000, 2.25);
    printf("tax = %.2f \n", tax);
    float salaryNetto = netSalary(50000, 2.25);
    printf("salary = %.2f\n", salaryNetto);
    return 0;
}
float netSalary(float salary, float taxAllowance){
    return salary - taxIsrael(salary, taxAllowance);
}
float taxIsrael(float salary, float taxAllowance){
    float tax = - taxAllowance * 216;
    if(salary < 6310){ //if (salary >=0 &&salary < 6310){
        return tax + salary * 0.1; //return tax +(salary - 0) * 0.1;
    }else{
        tax = tax + 6310 * 0.1; // tax = tax + (6310 - 0) * 0.1;
    }
    if(salary >= 6310 && salary < 9050){
        return tax + (salary - 6310) * 0.14;
    }else{
        tax = tax + (9050 - 6310)* 0.14;
    }
    if(salary >= 9050 && salary < 14530){
        return tax + (salary - 9050) * 0.2;
    }else{
        tax = tax + (14530 - 9050) * 0.2;
    }
    if(salary >= 14530 && salary < 20200){
        return tax+ (salary - 14530) * 0.31;
    }else{
        tax = tax + (20200 - 14530) * 0.31;
    }
    if(salary >= 20200 && salary < 42030){
        return tax + (salary - 20200) * 0.35;
    }else{
        tax = tax + (42030 - 20200) * 0.35;
    }
    if(salary >= 42030 && salary < 54130){
        return tax + (salary - 42030) * 0.47;
    }else{
        tax = tax + (54130 - 42030) * 0.47;
    }
    return tax + (salary - 54130) * 0.5;

}
```

Comment: Каждое >= можно выкинуть, потому что то же самое делает предыдущее условие с <.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, вам следует сделать что-то вроде такого (внимание, это псевдокод, лишь идея):

```
float taxIsrael(float salary, float taxAllowance){
    float tax = - taxAllowance * 216;
    const float A[]={0.0, 6310, 9050, 14530, 20200, 42030, 54130, 1e999};
    const float B[]={0.0, 0.1, 0.14, 0.2, 0.31, 0.35, 0.47, 0.5};

    size_t i=0;
    while (salary>=A[i] && salary<A[i+1]) {
        tax += A[i]*B[i];       
        ++i;
    }
    --i;
    tax += (salary - A[i])*B[i+1];
    return tax;
}
```

Я добавил в список констант бесконечность `1e999`, чтобы цикл гарантированно завершился. Я не тестировал код, но идея верная, может быть чуть подправите что там на что умножаться должно и уточните границы массивов.